# Carmichael Numbers and generators

Tags: prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

Suppose $n$ is a Carmichael number.

If, for a contradiction, we supposed that $n=p^k m$ for a prime $p$ and some $k\ge 2$ where $gcd(m,p)=1$. Let $g$ be a generator mod $p^2$.

I am looking to explain why there exists some integer $a$ such that

$$
a=g \; mod\; p^2
$$
$$
and
$$
$$a=1 \; mod \; m
$$

I know that if $p$ is a prime then there exist $h$ with $1 ≤ h < p$ and $g$
with $1 ≤ g < p^2$ such that $ord_p(h) = p − 1$ and $ord_p^{2} (g) = p(p − 1)$, that is, $h$ is a generator modulo $p$ and g is a generator modulo $p$ however I don't know how to apply this to my question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please give a reference for beotians who have not been introduced to Mr Carmichael (true: I never heard about these numbers, and I musn't be alone).

Comment: I assume you are asking what a carmichael number is? A carmichael number is a number that cannot be found to be composite using fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and precise answer.

Comment: The existence of $a$ is by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Could you explain further?